# Android Erisin ES8715V - Boot loop

Tags: adb, boot-loop

I have Erisin ES8715V and problem with boot loop.

Last time when I had this issue I entered in Recovery mode and did factory reset. I entered with holding power button and reset for 10 seconds.

Now I have again same issue and can't enter in Recovery mode.

Can someone help me is it possible something with ADB or maybe different way to enter into Recovery mode?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: adb/fastboot requires usb connection to PC, does this device support this? what did customer support say about your issue?

Comment: @alecxs 
Yes, this device support USB. 

I've tried to contact Customer, they only have marketign email and still waiting answer from them (disappointed).

Thanks for answer.

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3734376

Comment: https://androidmtk.com/use-rockchip-factorytool

Comment: https://androidmtk.com/use-rockchip-batch-tool